# Maddhatter Calendar view not being displayed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement madhatter calendar in Laravel, but I do not see any calendar after implementing the code.
I guess the problem I face is in these lines
`{!! $calendar_details->script() !!} {!! ($calendar_details->calendar()) !!}`...
and when `{{$calendar_details->script() }} {{ ($calendar_details->calendar()) }}`... It gives me the following [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXeyr.png).
Does someone has solution for it?